# Mongodb automatically write into capped collection

Tags: collections, triggers, mongodb, sharding

I need to manage the acquisition of many record at hour. About `1000000` records. And I need to get every second the last insert value for every primary key. It works quit well with sharding. I was thinking to try the use os capped collection to get only the last record for every primary key. In order to do this, I made two separated insert, there is a way, into `mongodb`, to make some kind of trigger to propagate the insert into a collection to another collection?

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB does not have any support for triggers or similar behavior.

The only way to do this is to make it happen in your code. So the code that writes the first entry should also write the second.

People have definitely requested triggers. If they are necessary for your solution, please cast a [vote on the feature request](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124).

Comment: OK, this is not officially supported but you can "roll your own" triggers in a sense. If you're using replication or master/slave, that master has an opLog (operations log) for all updates. You can write a small app that listens to that collection and performs the second insert. There will be a delay, but you can make it < 1s. Of course, you'll have to write some extra code and get into a lot more detail, but it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with "triggers is needed". People, MongoDB was created to be very fast and to provide as basic functionalities as can be. This is a power of this solution.

I think that here the best think is to create triggers inside Your application as a part of Data Access layer.